# Is it possible to split a large AES encrypted string and decrypt the parts one by one?

Tags: encryption, aes

Due to some platform restrictions our decryption can only handle up to 1 million bytes. The string we receive is larger. Is it possible to somehow split the encrypted data and decrypt the parts?

Comment: Please indicate your programming environment and possibly an SSCCE. Please read the FAQ before posting questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can cut it up into multiples of the block size.

You need to know the block chaining method used. If it is CBC or another one which uses the results of the previous block as the IV for the next block{^1], then you will have to handle saving the IV out of the last block of each batch and use it to feed into the next.

[^1]: so basically anything but ECB and CTR, although even with the latter you'll need to track the correct counter value.

Comment: Yes we use cipher block chaining (CBC) and PKCS5 padding.

Comment: so if we use AES256 we just need to split into multiples of 256 and extract the iv from the last block of each chunk and use this for the next chunk? is this what you mean?

Comment: Correct. For CBC, it is specifically the last block of ciphertext that you would need to use as the input IV for the next set - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29 is a good diagram explanation.

Comment: Officially only the first vector is the initialization vector. Many platforms supply either update or streaming functionality for their cipher implementations, so there is little need to create separate blocks to overcome memory problems. Otherwise the (direct) answer to the question is of course correct.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes, because AES encrypts and decrypts using blocks of bits. So you can decrypt as the blocks come in, but in the proper order...

Answer (score 0):

Normally you only have to split up your encrypted string if you want to split decryption over multiple processors or threads. Most platforms provide some method of **streaming** encryption/decryption. If that is not present, it should be relatively easy to create it yourself.